# I have no idea how 八九不离十 works?

Tags: word

My textbooks says  八九不离十 means pretty close and that makes sense to me, but the way they use it makes me lose my head.

“汤姆说考试八九不离十就可以了。” I think they are trying to say " 80/90% is close enough", but the way they use it doesn't make sense to me at all. What is a better sentence that includes 八九不离十 in it? If it makes sense, could you explain why?

Comment: You are right.   “汤姆说考试八九不离十就可以了。” makes little sense to a native speaker either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`八九不離十` means `almost there and I accept it` or `pretty close and I accept it`, the most important thing is `and I accept it`. The ten may be perfect but if nine or eight are still fine.

“汤姆说考试八九不离十就可以了。” means Tom doesn't chasing for perfect in test.

Comment: It is not a common usage of the idiom, but this answer is the closest to my understanding. "Not perfect" is the key.

Comment: yeah my mandarin textbook is inaccurate and outdated.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, “八九不离十” is very very informal. Even as a native speaker of Mandarin, I seldom use it. You should be careful when you want to use this phrase.

Secondly, Your example sentence “汤姆说考试八九不离十就可以了。” sounds very strange to me. I doubt a native speaker (at least in central mainland China) will use “八九不离十” in this way.

“八九不离十” means “相差无几” "差不多"，"very close to the fact but not exactly the fact"

> 你猜的八九不离十。 (Nǐ cāi de bā jiǔ bù lí shí.)
> Your guess is pretty close.

Update: An analysis of “八九不离十”

“八” = number 8 “九” = number 9 “不” = not “离” = "far away from" “十” = number 10

Literally, “八九不离十” means "number 8 and 9 are not far from number 10", "number 8 and 9 are pretty close to number 10", so it is used to mean "very close to the fact but not exactly the fact".

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure that the term is used correctly in “汤姆说考试八九不离十就可以了”. According to the dictionary, “八九不离十” means “nearly approaching the **fact**”, and using “fact” to describe exam results is not appropriate, so the sentence makes sense but isn’t grammatically right.

Here’s an example that the term is correctly used:

> 他猜得不对，但是八九不离十了。
> He guessed wrong, but is almost there.

Answer (score 0):

For simple, replace it with `差不多`. But the point is:
To understand what **object/target** is close to, or what `十` (the object) represents in the sentence.

`这电影不好看，跟我之前想的八九不离十（差不多）`
`十` represents `不好看(boring)`
The movie is boring anyway.

`这次考试结果，她能猜个八九不离十（差不多）`
`十` represents `考试结果(score)`
She guessed a close number.

`汤姆说考试八九不离十（差不多）就可以了`
Tom can accept an average score.
So the trick is, `十` represents `通过(passed)` in the sentence, NOT `Excellent(A+)`

Remember `十` is just an object, NOT a number, NOT ten out of ten, and Tom just wanna pass the exam.